# Type mismatch, found SortedSet, required Any

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When using `combinebyKey`, got an type mismatch error as follow

```
scala> rdd.map(x => (x._1, x._2))
          .combineByKey( (x: Int) => x, 
                         (acc: SortedSet[Int], x: Int) => (acc += x), 
                         (acc1: SortedSet[Int], acc2: SortedSet[Int]) => (acc1 ++= acc2))

<console>:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[Int], Int) => scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[Int]
 required: (Any, Int) => Any
       rdd.map(x => (x._1, x._2)).combineByKey( (x: Int) => x, (acc: SortedSet[Int], x: Int) => (acc += x), (acc1: SortedSet[Int], acc2: SortedSet[Int]) => (acc1 ++= acc2))
                                                                                             ^
<console>:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[Int], scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[Int]) => scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[Int]
 required: (Any, Any) => Any
       rdd.map(x => (x._1, x._2)).combineByKey( (x: Int) => x, (acc: SortedSet[Int], x: Int) => (acc += x), (acc1: SortedSet[Int], acc2: SortedSet[Int]) => (acc1 ++= acc2))
```

Why scala cannot treat `scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[Int]` as `Any`

Here is the code I tried:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet
val data = Array((1, 1, 1), 
                 (1, 1, 2),
                 (1, 1, 3),
                 (1, 2, 1),
                 (1, 2, 2),
                 (1, 2, 3), 
                 (2, 1, 1), 
                 (2, 1, 2), 
                 (2, 1, 3), 
                 (2, 2, 1), 
                 (2, 2, 2), 
                 (2, 2, 3))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

rdd.map(x => (x._1, x._2))
   .combineByKey( (x: Int) => x, 
                  (acc: SortedSet[Int], x: Int) => (acc += x), 
(acc1: SortedSet[Int], acc2: SortedSet[Int]) => (acc1 ++= acc2))
```

I expected to get
((1, (1,2)), (2, (1,2)), which value in the key/value pairs don't contain duplicated elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of the first function needs to be a sorted set, spark needs to know how to construct the combiners. Something like this should work

```
rdd.map(x => (x._1, x._2)).combineByKey( 
  (x: Int) => new mutable.TreeSet[Int] += x, 
  (acc: SortedSet[Int], x: Int) => (acc += x), 
  (acc1: SortedSet[Int], acc2: SortedSet[Int]) => (acc1 ++= acc2))
```